# bad connection between Windows and firestore in c#

Tags: c#, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, visual-studio-2022

Until yesterday everything was working fine. I could connected my app from Windows(. Net Framework 4.7.2), Android and iOS(. Net Maui 7.0) to Firestore without any problems.
Today without changes I can not connect windows to firebase. When I try, I get this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' in mscorlib.dll
Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1689930000.542000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3218,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1689930000.542000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"..\..\..\src\core\lib\transport\error_utils.cc","file_line":165,"grpc_status":14}]}")
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.WriteBatch.<CommitAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/WriteBatch.cs:line 226
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.DocumentReference.<CreateAsync>d__19.MoveNext() in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/DocumentReference.cs:line 106
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.CollectionReference.<AddAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/CollectionReference.cs:line 94
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at WindowsEnviromentTestDigitalForm.Form1.<btnInsertFix_Click>d__3.MoveNext()
```

This my code:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"privatykey.json";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);

FirestoreDb databaseFS = FirestoreDb.Create("appname");

CollectionReference collectionReference = databaseFS.Collection("Collection_Name");
Dictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>() 
{
      {"Test1", 0}, {"Test2", 1}, {"Test3", 3}
};

collectionReference.AddAsync(map);
```

Why does this issue appear randomly only for Windows?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a networking problem?

Comment: I tried with different connections, I tried with LAN, and 2 differents wi-fi but always with the same pc. I'm not able to try with another pc because is my buisness pc.

Comment: Did the firebase license expire?

Comment: I don't think so because it works for Android and iOS

Answer (score 1):

As of **21st of July, 2023**, **04:12 PDT**, you may experience increased test times and errors when deploying/testing your project on Firebase. This incident started on **20th of July, 2023, 10:30 PDT**.

This may affect Firebase users when deploying and testing new and current projects.

You may monitor the status through this link on [Firebase Status Dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/).

You may also reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) for additional assistance with regards to your concern.